# CSS3 Background Image Positioning

Tags: css

I decided to play with some CSS3 and ran into some problems with background images.  My background images (the hexagon and arrow) aren't displaying correctly.  The hexagon is not showing in the parent element and I can't get the arrow to move to the right.

I'm using border-images so that I can horizontally resize the elements.

Any Advice?

This is what it's supposed to look like ->
[image: Finished Navigation Example]

This is the hexagon ->
[image: Hexagon]

This is the Arrow ->
[image: Arrow]

This is the Anchor Element Background ->
[image: Anchor Background]

This is the List Item Element Background ->
[image: List Item Background]

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y6XL/)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Examples</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 107px;
    border-width: 1px 32px 1px 32px;
    -moz-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.li.background.png') 1 32 1 32 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.li.background.png') 1 32 1 32 stretch stretch;
    -o-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.li.background.png') 1 32 1 32 stretch stretch;
    border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.li.background.png') 1 32 1 32 stretch stretch;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    border-width: 1px 14px 1px 14px;
    -moz-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    -o-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 31px 0 0 17px;
    background: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.hex.background.png') no-repeat -50px center,
    url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.arrow.background.png') no-repeat right center;
    color: #d92701;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y6XL/3/)

After reading the A List Apart article on [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), I worked on a solution to this problem.  I used Abhidev's suggestion to divide the image into three parts.

This solution also allows me to shrink the width of each list item (e.g. providing a value other than auto to the *anchor* element).

**CSS**

```
nav {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
nav ul {
    height: 107px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 107px;
    position: relative;
}
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #d92701;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 4.5;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 107px; width: auto;
    background: transparent url('nav.background.expand.middle.png') repeat-x left top;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
nav li:before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    width: 64px;
    height: 107px;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent url('nav.background.expand.begin.png') no-repeat left top;
}
nav li:after {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: 58px;
    height: 107px;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent url('nav.background.expand.end.png') no-repeat right top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav><ul><li><a href="">Hello World</a></li><li><a href="">Hello</a></li><li><a href="">Hello World Hello World</a></li></ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited my css. Take a look at the this http://jsfiddle.net/8y6XL/1/

CSS

```
 nav {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px
}
li {
    background: url("http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.hex.background.png") no-repeat scroll 6px center, url("http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.arrow.background.png") no-repeat scroll 223px center, url("http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.li.background.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    border-width: 1px 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 107px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 271px;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    border-width: 1px 14px 1px 14px;

    -webkit-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    -o-border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    border-image: url('http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png') 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url("http://markschamel.com/graphics/themes/misc/nav.a.background.png") 1 14 1 14 stretch stretch;
    border-width: 1px 14px;
    color: #D92701;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 31px 0 0 8px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 138px;
}
```

if you want a stretchable li element, then stretching the image will be messy. I n that cas I suggest you to divide the image in 3 parts. 1.Left part including the left arrow angle and the hexagon 2.Right part including the small arrow and the right angular part 3.a 1px by 1px tile image.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't stretch if I change the text (i.e. to "Super Long Navigation Item")